# Animating a line with points taken from a array in cocos 2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

i am trying to achieve something like this . I get points from the web which i store in an array ,  using  those points i am trying to draw  a line . now  , the situation is due to fast iteration of my array my line visible once  & instance. Is there any way to slow-down this process because i want to show it like i am drawing a line ..i m rendering the line to a render texture without using draw function .. please help

Comment: please add some code .. how you are trying to achieve this

Comment: the code is not like this ..but you will get the idea

for (int i=0;i<[pointarray count];i++)
{
[self drawline: point1fromarray: AndPOintjustbeforePoint1];
}

-(void)drawline (point, previouspoint)
{
 CCRenderTexture *renderTarget = (CCRenderTexture *)[self getChildByTag:999];
    
    [renderTarget begin];
    
    ccDrawLine(CGPointMake (previouspoint, presentpoint));
     
    [renderTarget end]; 
}